# How to compare an object with an array and return a value

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

Say I have an object structured like this:

```
const carObj = {"1234":"Corvette","4321":"Subaru","8891":"Volvo"};
```

And I have an array that represents the key (or ID):

```
const myArray = [1234, 4321, 8891, 1234, 4321]
```

I want a loop, function, or something that will go through the object of arrays and return the value for the corresponding key. I am using vue.js and attempting to do this in a computed method. Any help would be much appreciated.

Expected output:

```
Corvette
Subaru
Volvo
Corvette
Subaru
```

Answer (score 3):

Just map the numbers array the returns new one based on the keys of the object  :

```
 const result = myArray.map(item=>carObj[item])
```

computed property :

```
computed:{
   result(){
        return this.myArray.map(item=>this.carObj[item])
      }

}
```

Comment: Note that this works because JS converts the integers in myArray to strings when using them as keys.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const carObj = {"1234":"Corvette","4321":"Subaru","8891":"Volvo"};
const myArray = [1234, 4321, 8891, 1234, 4321];

myArray.forEach((item) => {
  console.log(carObj[item]);
});
```